# Cassandra - Thrift/CQL query withoult using the row cache

Tags: cassandra

My column family has enabled row cache. I have batch processing, which goes over all rows to find those which are suppose to be removed. As result row cache is being flushed - it does not contain "real data", but results of my batch processing.

Can I execute Thrift/CQL query which will tell Cassandra to avoid row cache even when it's enabled ? This would be useful for Map-Reduce algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

Why avoid the row cache as it is designed to always have the same data as the data on disk?  (ie. writes coming in write to the row cache first then the disk and reads do the same).  What is the use case for avoiding the row cache which has the most up to date data?

Also, I hear row cache only helps in like 5% of use cases and in general it should be left off.  I think PlayOrm's use case for using a row cache might be one of the 5% where it can tell cassandra to cache the 3 index column families it uses so that Scalable-SQL queries are fast into it's partitions so queries would be much faster but most use-cases slow the system down with it's row caching.

Comment: We have skinny rows with heavy read access - this is perfect use case for row cache. Why should I load into row cache data that I need to read only once (during batch job) ?